# how can i make like and unlike button more smooth Using django and javascript in python framework django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

“Like” and “Unlike” buttons with icons
Users should be able to click a button or link on any post to toggle whether or not they “like” that post.
Using JavaScript asynchronously let the server know to update the like count (as via a call to fetch) and then update the post’s like count displayed on the page, without requiring a reload of the entire page.

problem is

1. I cannot toggle between the like and unliked icons when I am in the unlike icon
2. when I like one post liked count goes to all posts.
3. look like my code is beginner code

## In html file inside Django templates

```
{% if post.id in postLiked  %}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary fa fa-thumbs-down" id="{{ post.id }}" onclick="likeOrUnlike('{{ post.id }}', '{{ postLiked }}')"></button>
                    {% else %}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary fa fa-thumbs-up" id="{{ post.id }}" onclick="likeOrUnlike('{{ post.id }}', '{{ postLiked }}')"></button>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <h3 class="col-4">Like: {{ likes.count  }}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

## In models.py

```
class LikeOrUnlike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likeByUser')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='postLiked')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} liked this {self.post}'
```

## In urls.py

```
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path('like/<int:post_id>', views.like,name='like'),
    path('unlike/<int:post_id>', views.unlike,name='unlike')
```

## In views.py

```
def index(request):
     

    likes = LikeOrUnlike.objects.all()
    postLiked = []
    try:
        for like in likes:
            if like.user.id == request.user.id:
                postLiked.append(like.post.id)
    except:
        postLiked = [] 
    return render(request, "network/index.html",{
        'likes':likes,
        'postLiked': postLiked


})# function for liking post
def like(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    likePost = LikeOrUnlike(user=user, post=post)
    likePost.save()
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Liked"})

# function for unliking post
def unlike(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    unlikePost = LikeOrUnlike.objects.filter(user=user, post=post)
    unlikePost.delete()
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Unliked"})
```

## JavaScript code

```
// javaScript to like and unlike
    function likeOrUnlike(id, postLiked){
        const btn = document.getElementById(`${id}`);

        btn.classList.remove('fa-thumbs-up')
        btn.classList.remove('fa-thumbs-down')
        
        if(postLiked.indexOf(id) >= 0){
            var liked = true;
        }else{
            var liked = false;
        }

        if(liked === true){
            fetch(`/unlike/${id}`)
            .then(response => response.json)
            .then(result => {
                btn.classList.add("fa-thumbs-up")
            })
        }else{
            fetch(`/like/${id}`)
            .then(response => response.json)
            .then(result => {
                btn.classList.add("fa-thumbs-down")
            })
        }
        liked = !liked
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters I must say that you can improve your `Models` by using `many-to-many` [relationship API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/#examples-of-model-relationship-api-usage), but since that is not the focus of your question I will not get into this.

Lets start with rendering the `Post` list. For that we need all posts and the current `User` liked posts  we can query that information using the stablished relation:

views.py

```py
def list_posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    user_liked_posts = request.user.likeByUser.all().values_list("post", flat=True)

    context = {"posts": posts, "user_liked_posts": user_liked_posts}

    return render(request, "posts/list.html", context)
```

list.html

```py
{% for post in posts %}
<p>{{post.title}}</p>
<p>{{post.body}}</p>

<button id="like_button_{{post.id}}" onclick="LikeOrUnlike('{{post.id}}')">
    {% if post.id in user_liked_posts %}
    <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-down"></i>
    {% else %}
    <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up"></i>
    {% endif %}
</button>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    ...
</script>
```

This way, when first rendering the page we setup the correct icon if the `User` has liked the post or not.

### Fetch

The second part is the like / dislike action, which I made using the same principle. Also, only one view is necessary to handle such action.

First, write [`getCookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) function, to retrieve `csrftoken` and attach it to the [`header`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request). Then, write the `async` function that is responsible for updating the information both on backend and frontend:

list.html (script)

```py
<script>
    function getCookie(name) {
        ...
    }

    const LikeOrUnlike = async (id) => {
        const thumbs_up = '<i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up"></i>';
        const thumbs_down = '<i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-down"></i>';

        const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
        const user = "{{request.user.id}}";

        const response = await fetch("/post/like/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ user_id: user, post_id: id }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();

        const like_button_element = document.getElementById(
            `like_button_${id}`
        );
        const likes_count_element = document.getElementById(
            `likes_count_${id}`
        );

        let num_likes = parseInt(likes_count_element.innerHTML);

        if (data.liked) {
            like_button_element.innerHTML = thumbs_down;
            likes_count_element.innerHTML = num_likes + 1;
        } else {
            like_button_element.innerHTML = thumbs_up;
            likes_count_element.innerHTML = num_likes - 1;
        }
    };
</script>
```

views.py

```py
def like_or_unlike_fetch(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    user_id = data.pop("user_id")
    post_id = data.pop("post_id")

    user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    data.update({"user": user, "post": post})

    post = LikeOrUnlike.objects.filter(**data)
    if not post:
        LikeOrUnlike.objects.create(**data)
        liked = True
    else:
        post.delete()
        liked = False

    return JsonResponse({"liked": liked})
```

Comment: irst, write getCookie function, to retrieve csrftoken and attach it to the header.How to get cookies and user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id ) i do not have get_user_model()

Comment: thank for answering my question but it not working can you teach me please

Comment: [`get_user_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) is a built in function, that you can use to import the `User` model. `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`.

Comment: `getCookie` function is in the reference on my answer. But since I am making the comment, you can find the function in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax)

Comment: still not working not even displaying thumbs up and down

Comment: please help me i am newbie so i know a little

Comment: I used `Fontawesome`, you can import via [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome), just get the first one  `all.min.css`.

Comment: it also does not work.

Comment: should i use my previous code to and which which??